# Correct way to remove a red wire from a circuit

Tags: electrical

Reference: [Can I convert a 3-way switch that switches half duplex outlets into an outlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/182601/can-i-convert-a-3-way-switch-that-switches-half-duplex-outlets-into-an-outlet)

My answer to the referenced question involves removing the red wire between two 3-way switches and converting the bundle to an always hot bundle.  Essentially making a 14-3 bundle do the job of a 14-2.

What is the proper way to deal with the extra wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cap each end with a wire nut and leave it in its junction box.

Do not trim away the ends of the wires. That could confuse a future maintainer, and someone might find a use for that wire someday.

If you maintain infrastructure documentation on your home, add a note describing the abandoned wire.

If you do not maintain infrastructure documentation on your home, start now. Begin with a note describing the abandoned wire.